# Share cache between Controllers and Scheduler

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I am using play framework (2.3.7) and lot of my controllers use the Cache (which comes with Play Framework).

I am writing a scheduled task which should update the cache periodically
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks

However I get an error saying that there must be an active application in order to use the cache.

So is there any way the controllers, scheduled tasks can use the cache together?

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the current application into the agent.

I see you tag play 2.3 (meanwhile you insert link to the 2.6 documentation that could be different). So try just to add that import into the scheduled code:

```
import play.api.Play.current
```